# Telerik CDN Support

Tags: telerik, cdn

According to Telerik:

To distribute your web asset group via content delivery network you should use the ContentDeliveryNetworkUrl() method:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Scripts(scripts =>
            scripts.AddGroup("CommonScript", group => 
                group.Add("~/Scripts/Core.js")
                     .Add("~/Scripts/Stuff.js")
                     .Combined(true)
                     .CacheDurationInDays(365)
                     .Compress(true)
                     .ContentDeliveryNetworkUrl("http://mycdn.com/CommonScript.js")
            )
```

I'm confused by this, specifically:

```
ContentDeliveryNetworkUrl("http://mycdn.com/CommonScript.js")
```

How does this file get created on the CDN? I assume Core.js and Stuff.js get combined, cached, and compressed then uploaded to my CDN automatically? Or is CommonScript.js another JS file that get's added to the combined script? If so, then the combined script gets served locally still, and not from the CDN?

Telerik say VERY VERY little about how all this work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

- Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upload the combined file by yourself. The ContentDeliveryNetworkUrl just tells the script registrar to output that value instead of core.js and stuff.js.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still a bit unclear. Does the script registrar create the combined script for me? What will be its file name and where will it be created at? And if this is the case, I still don't see how this works: ContentDeliveryNetworkUrl("http://mycdn.com/CommonScript.js"); Can you tell me the steps I need to take in order to setup scenario above?

Comment: The ScriptRegistar combines files at runtime when the browser requests the asset.axd file. If you need to use CDN you must combine the files by yourself and upload it to your CDN. If you need to use Telerik CDN (which serves only telerik scripts) - you can check this http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/web-assets-telerik-cdn-support.html

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. The obvious question then becomes, what value does the asset manager provide if you have to combine the files yourself and upload them to the CDN?

Comment: The asset manager does a few other things - emits the initialization JavaScript for all Telerik components on the page. I think this is important too :)